# Dapper insert item into returned list

Tags: c#, dapper

Trying to add a "Select One" or " " item to a result returned from Dapper so I can display that as a starting point in a DropDownList.

I have tried;

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString()))
        {
            List<Zone> Zonelist = conn.Query<Zone>("GetZone", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Zone>();

            Zonelist.Add(" ");

            CB_Zones.DataSource = Zonelist;
            CB_Zones.DisplayMember = "ZoneName";
            CB_Zones.ValueMember = "ZoneID";
        }
```

but it says I cannot convert from 'string' to 'Metrics_Data.Zone'(the list I'm returning)

The following code works fine with a 'DropDown', but when I change the Control to a 'DropDownList' it does not work, I know its because it wont allow an input different from the defined list.

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString()))
        {
            List<Zone> Zonelist = conn.Query<Zone>("GetZone", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Zone>();


            CB_Zones.DataSource = Zonelist;
            CB_Zones.DisplayMember = "ZoneName";
            CB_Zones.ValueMember = "ZoneID";

            CB_Zones.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

How do I go about added a "Select One" or " " to the dapper list with out having to add that to the Database Dapper is pulling from?

Comment: `ZoneList` is a list of `Zone`s, so you can't add `" "` to it because that's a `string`. What you are trying to do may not be the best solution. Is this WinForms/Web/WPF/other? For example, some controls allow you to specify a watermark to display when there is no selection.

Comment: I'M using WinForms for the application

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to solve this is to add a pseudo-object with an invalid id at the start of the list before binding the data, e.g.:

```
var pseudoZone = new Zone() { ZoneName = "Select one...", ZoneID = -1 };
Zonelist.Insert(pseudoZone, 0);
CB_Zones.DataSource = Zonelist;
CB_Zones.DisplayMember = "ZoneName";
CB_Zones.ValueMember = "ZoneID";
```

If for some reason you cannot create a pseudo-object, you can create a new list with empty-entry and the required data from the zone list, e.g.

```
var pseudoZone = Tuple.Create("Select one...", -1);
var items = new Tuple<string, int>[]{ pseudoZone }
    .Union(Zonelist)
    .ToArray();
CB_Zones.DataSource = items;
CB_Zones.DisplayMember = "Item1";
CB_Zones.ValueMember = "Item2";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString()))
    {
        List<Zone> Zonelist = conn.Query<Zone>("GetZone", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<Zone>();

        Zonelist.Insert(0, new Zone() { ZoneID = -1 , ZoneName = "Select one..." });

        CB_Zones.DataSource = Zonelist;
        CB_Zones.DisplayMember = "ZoneName";
        CB_Zones.ValueMember = "ZoneID";

        CB_Zones.Text = "";
    }
```